# Can't stop local service on android

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an application which is planned to send new notifications via bluetooth. (Just logcat yet.) The app has a NotificationListenerService, which starts when the app starts or when you press the start service button. (button4 in the code.) It works fine, but I can't stop it with the stopService command.
Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.goston.arduwatch;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
Intent startServiceIntent;
Button button1 ;
Button button2 ;
Button button3 ;
Button button4 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    checkBTState();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationListener.class);
    startNotificationListener();
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onEnableBluetooth();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopNotificationListener();
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startNotificationListener();
        }
    });
}
private void onEnableBluetooth(){
    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
private void stopNotificationListener(){
    stopService(startServiceIntent);
}
private void startNotificationListener(){
    startService(startServiceIntent);
}
private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on

    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) {

    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        } else {
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

And here is the NotificationListener.java:

```
package com.goston.arduwatch;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public void onCreate () {
    showNotification();
}
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    //---show current notification---
    Log.i("","---Current Notification---");
    Log.i("", "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    Log.i("","--------------------------");
    //---show all active notifications---
    Log.i("","===All Notifications===");
    for (StatusBarNotification notif :
            this.getActiveNotifications()) {
        Log.i("","ID :" + notif.getId() + "\t" + notif.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + notif.getPackageName());        }
    Log.i("","=======================");
}
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(
        StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("","---Notification Removed---");
    Log.i("","ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    Log.i("","--------------------------");
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("","Service Started");
    return START_STICKY;
}


private void showNotification() {
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher),getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height),true);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(bm)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_text));
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(01, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mNotificationManager.cancel(01);
    Log.i("","Service Stopped");
}


}
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If maybe stops, then I can't see it because onDestroy is never executed (in the service)

Comment: give some value in tag in on destroy and check. you are giving just second value and first value is empty.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, because it's working in onNotificationPosted and also the notification stays there.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this.stopSelf() in your service's onDestroy method as well as you have used START_STICKY flag which will auto create your service if it will destory.So use START_NOT_STICKY flag if you don't want service to run even if your app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems, that I could manage to found a solution to the problem. I changed the two buttons to a switch (just for the look), and the toggle a boolean and restart the service at each change. The service check the boolean's value and also puts it in an own bool. If it is true, the service shows the notification and starts sending me things, and if it is false, it hides the notifcation and does nothing. It is complicated, but works.